# Why does Wordnet fail to convert dict files to bdb on Mac OS?

Tags: ruby, wordnet

I am trying to get Ruby Wordnet to convert the data files t dbd but convertdb.rb gives a segmentation fault at the end of running.  ANy idea whats going on or how to investigate and resolve this?

```
Checkpointing DB and cleaning logs...done.
done.

convertdb.rb: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0014e8 d:0014e8 TOP   
---------------------------

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested Ruby-WordNet under Ruby 1.9.2 (I'm the author), and the author of the bdb library it depends on died before 1.9.2 came out, so I don't think the version of the library that comes with the source has really been tested under it either.

You may wish to try the version of the bdb library [that's been maintained by Akinori MUSHA on github](https://github.com/knu/ruby-bdb), as I believe he's kept it up to date with 1.9.2 fixes.

It's also possible that I'm doing something wrong in the conversion script that's just tickled by 1.9.2. If you try the Github version of bdb and it doesn't work, let me know and I'll try to track down the problem with the conversion script.